# Xamarin project has seemingly lost reference to Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I was having many errors with my Xamarin project not being able to recognize the Android namespace and read that the solution was to delete the contents of the /bin folder and let it re-build from scratch.

I did that and now I am getting the error here: [image: Error]. The only thing I've found is that a small number of other people have had this error and there is no solution in their threads. Under references the path to Mono.Android.dll is correct (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.0\Mono.Android.dll), and the file exists. I can remove the reference and re-add it and will still see the same error.

Does anyone know how I can fix this and get back to my previous set of mysterious time-consuming Xamarin errors?

Comment: It is complaining about `monotouch` which is iOS and not Android. Your `monotouch` reference is obviously not compatible with any Android profiles.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I don't see a reference to monotouch under iOS References, and under my Android project I see only a reference to Mono.Android, which breaks everything if removed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide the build log

Comment: @Cheesebaron Sorry for the delay, I have it here: https://pastebin.com/qZnYkC62

Comment: Please provide the diagnostics log and please don't put it in pastebin, but edit your question and add it there. Otherwise, try pop open the csproj file and see if for some reason a monotouch reference has snuck its way inside there. Or maybe you are referencing some library which does it. The diagnostic build log will reveal that.

Comment: According to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68785/cannot-find-monotouch-dll-how-to-resolve-this-error), you might use some IOS thing in android. Which line give this error?